# How to send screenshot to any mail recipient using selenium

Tags: email, selenium-webdriver, webpage-screenshot

How can I send any screenshot captured using selenium web driver to a mail recipient?

Comment: Provide us the code and we ll solve your problem. This is not the way to ask question on SO .Go through https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @AkashRaj can you please read up on the following material and make sure your question has a [**Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? Else this question will attract negative reactions. Start by showing us some of your work on the matter.

Comment: @AkashRaj Can you consider showing us your work please? Thanks

Comment: As of now I have done coding for getting the snapshot only. I need to code for the next move. Will update it soon.

Answer (score 0):

In c# you can use

```
using Outlook1=Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook;
```

Add reference of Above

```
 Outlook1.Application outlookApp1 = new Outlook1.Application();
                Outlook1.MailItem mailItem = (Outlook1.MailItem)outlookApp1.CreateItem(Outlook1.OlItemType.olMailItem);
                outlookApp1.CreateItem(Outlook1.OlItemType.olMailItem);
                mailItem.Subject = "Your subject";
                mailItem.To = "Email id";
     mailItem.Importance = Outlook1.OlImportance.olImportanceLow;
                mailItem.Display(false);
                mailItem.Send();
```

You can even add attachments